# Redux Toolkit, component does not re-render after RTK query is fulfilled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a child component like so:

```
import { skipToken } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import moment from "moment";
import {
  useFetchAccountQuery,
  useFetchTransactionsQuery,
} from "./accountApiSlice";

const TransactionsTable = () => {
  const { data: accountData } = useFetchAccountQuery();

  const changesSince: string = moment().subtract(7, "d").toISOString();

  let params = {
    accountId: accountData?.accountId,
    categoryId: accountData?.defaultCategoryId,
    changesSince,
  };

  const paramsAreGood: boolean = params.accountId && params.categoryId ? true : false;

  const { data: transactions, isSuccess: transactionsSuccess } = useFetchTransactionsQuery(paramsAreGood ? params : skipToken);

  return (
    <>
      {transactionsSuccess && (
        <div>
          <h1>Number of transactions: {transactions?.length}</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default TransactionsTable;
```

I am making two queries, then using the `accountId` and `categoryId` from the 1st query to pass to the 2nd query so that I can make the transactions query and get the data.

In Chrome's Network tab, I can see that my `useFetchTransactionsQuery()` fires and I get data back.

[image: chrome network tab]

However, my component remains blank and I do not get:

```
<h1>Number of transactions: <some number></h1>
```

Here is a screenshot from Redux Dev Tools too:

[image: redux dev tools]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was this line:

```
const changesSince: string = moment().subtract(7, "d").toISOString();
```

I've no idea why, but I ditched moment for dayjs and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think before you set values to param  you should check if useFetchAccountQuery has returned any data yet, as useFetchAccountQuery is an async function and i think the param value is set before account data is fatched

try it like this

```
import { skipToken } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import moment from "moment";
import {
  useFetchAccountQuery,
  useFetchTransactionsQuery,
} from "./accountApiSlice";

const TransactionsTable = () => {
  const { data: accountData, isSucceess: AccountDataSuccess } = useFetchAccountQuery();

  const changesSince: string = moment().subtract(7, "d").toISOString();

  let params ;
  if(AccountDataSuccess && accountData ){
     params = {
       accountId: accountData?.accountId,
       categoryId: accountData?.defaultCategoryId,
       changesSince,
    }
   };

  const paramsAreGood: boolean = params.accountId && params.categoryId ? true : false;

  const { data: transactions, isSuccess: transactionsSuccess } = useFetchTransactionsQuery(paramsAreGood ? params : skipToken);

  return (
    <>
      {transactionsSuccess && (
        <div>
          <h1>Number of transactions: {transactions?.length}</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default TransactionsTable;
```

Please annotate the param accordingly if your are using typescript.

I hope this works. I use this type of pattern in my work and it works.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. TypeScript isn't happy because `params` can be `undefined` and if you guard `useFetchTransactionsQuery` behind an `if` statement, Redux complains that you can't have hooks inside if statements.

Comment: oh, sorry about that. I have another idea, make param a state value, and call setSate to set the value of param inside of the `if` statement. RTk Query caches the data so `useFetchAccountQuery` will not make a network request 2nd time the component get re-rended after state update. Also, put all your hooks at the top level of your component, react doc recommends that.